# git repository at remote location using https

Tags: java, git, https, apache2, jgit

I need to create remote repository from client location using JGit Eclipse API. I have also integrate Apache server to access repository using HTTPS Protocol. So using HTTPS and JGit I need to create remote repository from client.

Till now i have done all operation with local repository like

1. Create Bare repository
2. Create Local repository
3. Open an existing repository
4. Add Files or Folder in local repository
5. Commit in local repository
6. Push data from local repository to master repository
7. Pull data from master repository to local repository

Source code for same:

```
public void createBareRepository(File bareRepoLocation) throws IllegalStateException, GitAPIException, IOException {

    bareRepoLocation.delete();

    Git.init().setBare(true).setDirectory(bareRepoLocation).call();

    Repository repository = FileRepositoryBuilder.create(new File(bareRepoLocation.getAbsolutePath(), Constants.DOT_GIT));

    repository.close();
}



public void createLocalRepository(File localRepoLocation) throws IllegalStateException, GitAPIException, IOException {

    localRepoLocation.delete();

    Git.init().setBare(false).setDirectory(localRepoLocation).call();

    Repository repository = FileRepositoryBuilder.create(new File(localRepoLocation.getAbsolutePath(), Constants.DOT_GIT));

    System.out.println("Created a new repository at " + repository.getDirectory());
    repository.close();
}
private Repository openRepository(String localRepoLocation) throws IOException {
    FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
    Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(new File(localRepoLocation)).readEnvironment() 
            .findGitDir() // scan up the file system tree
            .build();

    return repository;

}

public void addFilesToLocalRepository(String localRepoLocation, File needToAdd) throws IOException, NoFilepatternException, GitAPIException {
    Repository repository = openRepository(localRepoLocation+File.separator+Constants.DOT_GIT);
    Git git = new Git(repository);
    git.add().addFilepattern(needToAdd.getName()).call();

}

public void commitInLocalRepository(String localRepoLocation, String commitMsg) throws IOException, NoHeadException, NoMessageException, UnmergedPathsException,
        ConcurrentRefUpdateException, WrongRepositoryStateException, RejectCommitException, GitAPIException {
    Repository repository = openRepository(localRepoLocation+File.separator+Constants.DOT_GIT);
    Git git = new Git(repository);
    RevCommit commitCommand = git.commit().setMessage(commitMsg).call();

}

public void pushDataToMasterRepository(File currentRepoLocation, String masterRepoLocation, String userName, String password) throws IOException, InvalidRemoteException,
        TransportException, GitAPIException {
    Repository repository = openRepository(currentRepoLocation.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + Constants.DOT_GIT);
    Git git = new Git(repository);

    StoredConfig config = repository.getConfig();
    config.setString("remote", "origin", "url", masterRepoLocation);
    config.setString("remote", "origin", "fetch", "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*");
    // fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    config.save();

    git.push().setProgressMonitor(new TextProgressMonitor()).setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(userName, password)).call();

}


public void pullDataFromMasterRepository(File currentRepoLocation, String masterRepoLocation, String userName, String password) throws IOException,
        WrongRepositoryStateException, InvalidConfigurationException, DetachedHeadException, InvalidRemoteException, CanceledException, RefNotFoundException,
        NoHeadException, TransportException, GitAPIException, URISyntaxException {
    Repository repository = openRepository(currentRepoLocation.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + Constants.DOT_GIT);

    StoredConfig config = repository.getConfig();
    config.setString("remote", "origin", "url", masterRepoLocation);
    config.setString("remote", "origin", "fetch", "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*");
    // fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    config.save();
    Git git = new Git(repository);

    PullCommand pull = git.pull();
    // pull.setProgressMonitor(new TextProgressMonitor());
    PullResult result = pull.setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(userName, password)).call();
}
```

Using above i am able to do all operation on on local machine with bare and local repository.

> The Problem i am facing is: If i am able to push data using HTTPS to existing remote repository(that means i able to write in that directory) than why should i am not able to create new repository at remote location. I need a code for creating repository at remote server using HTTPS.
>
> What type of changes need to be done in **createBareRepository** method
>
> **if you have any other solution please let me know**

Comment: please write what you have achieved so far (code sample, ...), otherwise no one is willing enough to help you out.

Comment: if any one know please let me help.

Comment: JGit does not support what you are trying to accomplish. It can clone an existing remote repository, but since it is running locally it cannot initialize a remote repository. You will want to create a web service that you can run on the remote server. This web service in turn can then use JGit to create a local repository (using the code you have posted in your  question).